# http post password to node.js server from angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-post

This is bugging me. I know I can do the following:

```
$http.post('https://url:8080/api/registerUser?username=' + usrName + '&usrPassword=' + usrPassword);
```

But I'm guessing this isn't the right way of passing a password to the server. So I've tried this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url2,
    data: {
        userName: encodeURIComponent(usrName), 
        userPassword: encodeURIComponent(usrPassword)
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

But I just can't find the data anywhere on my req in node.js when it receives it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check browser console if you are getting an error

Comment: I aint getting any error

Comment: The data is simply not to be found on the req object

Comment: try this on client side and check whether is really encoded or not. console.log(encodeURIComponent(usrPassword))

Comment: Switch to `https` protocol

Comment: But where in the req object is this data supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

You can find:

- POST data on `req.body`
- GET parameters on `req.query`
- Route parameters on `req.params`

req.body.userName for your example

Comment: req.body is undefined for me :/

Comment: Make sure your bodyparser configuration is correct/matches your content-type header. [reference](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)